# pandas create separate dataframe for each excel sheet

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file with about 20 sheets. Each sheets contain different type of data
I would like to loop the excel and create a data frame for each of these sheets with data frame name equal to the sheet name.

Tried different solution without success

Answer (score 0):

You can create dictionary of DataFrames by parameter `sheet_name=None` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=None)

print (dfs['sheetname1'])
print (dfs['sheetname2'])
```